# Can you downgrade Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server, minecraft-pi-edition

I have Minecraft Pi version on my Raspberry Pi and I wanted to be able to play with people on MC:PE. However, when I go to connect the device to the Pi's server it says `Outdated Server!`

I *know* that you can connect MC:PE and MC:Pi, they are both based off MC:PE code and I've read all over the place of people doing it! However, my PE version is 0.8 and that isn't compatible with MC:Pi 0.11, whereas MC:PE version 0.6 is.

My question is, is there a way to downgrade the MC:PE version without messing up worlds and being able to revert back to MC:PE 0.8 after playing with my Pi?

I figured this question would be more on-topic here than Raspberry Pi SE because it is an issue with MC:PE as opposed to the RPi.

Comment: You can't really downgrade apps with Android or iOS... sorry! :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do that would be to both: have your device rooted (jailbroke) and possess a copy of the outdated version.

I would check around and see if there is a modder community based around pocket edition. If you do have a rooted device. They would be the place to have a chance at that file.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is an old question, but you can actually just poke around a bit online and you will be able to find an application download for iOS/Android. Just search for a specific version. For Android, just look for "MC:PE version [version number] apk". For iOS, search for "MC:PE version [version number] ipa".